# Java filter list to generic type T

Tags: java

How can I do the following (this doesn't compile):

```
<T> List<T> getElementsOf() {
    return list.stream()
            .filter(x -> x instanceof T)
            .map(x -> (T) x)
            .collect(toList());
}
```

What would be example of usage? Ideally, it should be like `obj.<Derived>getElementsOf()`.

Comment: Could you be more specific on your needs, requirements, problem, ...

Comment: what is the type of `list` would it be `object` - if that is the case `instanceof` would not work

Comment: You may be interested in Guava's [`Iterables.filter()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#filter-java.lang.Iterable-java.lang.Class-). Note the first stream equivalent, which is identical to @Sweeper's solution.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Although the other answer pretty much does the job, here's a better one:

```
<T> List<T> getElementsOf(Class<T> clazz) {
    return list.stream()
            .filter(clazz::isInstance)
            .map(clazz::cast)
            .collect(toList());
}
```

Notice that the `clazz::isInstance` thingy. Instead of comparing the two classes, it uses the `isInstance` method. According to the docs, this is equivalent to `instanceof`, which is what you wanted in the first place.

> This method is the dynamic equivalent of the Java language instanceof operator.

Comment: I think you can also `map(clazz::cast)` instead of `map(x -> (T) x)`.

Comment: @lexicore Oh I didn't notice that! Edited now!

Answer (score 1):

I got the following:

```
<T> List<T> getChildrenOf(Class<T> clazz) {
    return children.stream()
            .filter(node -> node.getClass() == clazz)
            .map(node -> clazz.<T>cast(node))
            .collect(toList());
}

List<Mesh> nameNodes = b.getChildrenOf(Mesh.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that generic type information is erased at runtime, so to make that even clearer I exchanged the `T` with `Object`. Actually the `Object` wouldn't be there too, but I kept it to make it clearer, where the `T` was:

```
List<Object> getElementsOf() {
    return list.stream()
        .filter(x -> x instanceof Object) // this is legal, as Object is an actual type, T isn't
        .map(x -> (Object) x)
        .collect(toList());
}
```

As you can see now, this doesn't make much sense. There is no way to infer the type without passing it as parameter. You already got the solution yourself and I only wanted to make it clearer also for others not so familiar with generics.

```
<T> List<T> getElementsOf(Class<T> type) {
    return list.stream()
               .filter(type::isInstance)
               .map(type::cast)
               .collect(toList());
}
```

If we exchange `T` now with Object, we will see, that the type is still here and so you can cast it appropriately:

```
List getElementsOf(Class type) {
    return list.stream()
               .filter(type::isInstance) // is type an Object? is it Long? we don't mind... we passed it and we deliver it
               .map(type::cast) // actually this isn't really needed, if you have a return type of List (as you already filtered for the types you want)
               .collect(toList());
}
```

Note also, that with that method you will never get `null` values when supplying a type. `isInstance` will return `false` in such a case.